# What is topological space?

Tags: general-topology

I've just read definition of topological space on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space), but for me it doesn't make any sense. Defining a topological space as a family of subsets that satisfies certain conditions, they call the elements of this family *open sets*. But you can easily come up with a example of such family whose elements are not open (nested intervals). They must be missing something... or me. Please, clarify this for me.

Comment: The idea is to $\textit{declare}$ the subsets of that family satisfying certain conditions as $\textit{your open sets}$

Comment: @Carnby Ok, but they go further and tell us that continuous map between two sets is such map that transforms an open set into an open set. But it is a property of our open set in traditional meaning. How can I apply this to closed sets like in the example I gave?

Comment: @Euler-Maskerony Could you please explain your 'nested interval' construction in detail?

Comment: No. That is not the definition of a continuous map. A map is continuous iff the inverse of an open set is open. There are many logical equivalents (e.g. the inverse of a closed set is closed). Some of them are more useful than others for some problems.

Comment: @erpxyr2001 I thought, that if we take $X=[1,0]$ and then $\tau = \{[0.5-\frac{1}{i},0.5+\frac{1}{i}] | i \in \mathbb{Z}_+/\{1\}\}$. Then elements of $\tau$ satisfy all conditions, but elements of $\tau$ are not open (again, in calculus meaning). So, I don't understand how with closed subsets I can define continuous function.

Comment: A function can be made continuous or discontinuous by changing the topology. For example when working with the discrete topology every function is continuous because every subset is open. The usual metric topology from calculus is the most familiar but it's not the only one.

Comment: @Euler-Maskerony The intrinsic definition of continuity (i.e. the inverse of all open sets are open), but what it actually means changes according to the context (or the open sets that you've chosen). So in this case you have to abandon the traditional Euclidean notion of open sets and substitute them with the $\tau$ defined.

Comment: @erpxyr2001 But there is no information in internet about why these two completely different definitions of open sets (from calculus and from topology) both can be used to define the same definition of continuous function? I can't just believe it.

Comment: The topological definition generalizes the definition from calculus. Or, if you prefer, the open sets and continuous functions you know from calculus are a special case which fits into the definition of a general topological space. Of course you have to prove it (prove that the union of calculus-open sets is calculus-open; prove that a calculus-continuous function has calculus-open sets as inverse images of calculus-open sets, etc. We don't claim this is completely obvious; some work has to be done and can be found in a topology or calculus textbook.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **historical**.  In the space of real numbers, there were defined some subsets called "open".  Then in Euclidean space.  Later, in metric space, certain sets were called "open" and used in the same way: to define convergence, to define continuous function, etc.  Still later, for use is spaces more general than metric spaces, the properties of "open sets"  that were usefule were taken as a definition for "topoogical space".

Comment: I still don't understand. How then can I define continuous function for topological space? It relies on the definition of open space from calculus, but in my example subsets of $X$ are not open.

Comment: @Euler-Maskerony That's the point - it doesn't. The open subsets from calculus are called that because they satisfy the axioms of open sets of a topology. Not the other way around. For example, there is the discrete topology on the real line in which every set is open and every function is continuous.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Wow, I didn't know that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov Why then GEdgar wrote that open sets firstly were introduced for metric spaces?

Comment: @Euler-Maskerony Because that's the order it happened historically. At first open sets were defined for subsets of the real line, then for metric spaces, then for topologies on arbitrary sets. But each subsequent definition does not rely on the previous one, it instead generalizes and weakens it.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov So these to definitions has no really much in common and for topology defined as such they can be used for continuous function definition?

Comment: @Euler-Maskerony They do have a lot in common. Each is a special case of the following one. The open sets of the real line, defined as unions of open intervals, are the open sets of the real line with the classical topology.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure of defining a topology on a set $X$ is like this: first one picks any subset $O$ of the power set $\mathfrak{P}(X)$ and **declare** that all elements in $O$ are open sets. But immediately we'd notice that $O$ shouldn't be that *arbitrary*, and we call $O$ *legal* if it satisfies the following axioms (or simply, definitions, and you can find them on wikipedia as well):

1. $\emptyset\in O, X\in O$.
2. $\forall \left\{ O_{\alpha}\mid \alpha \in \mathcal{A} \right\} $ in which every $O_\alpha\in O$, $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}{O_{\alpha}}\in O$.
3. $\forall O_1, \cdots, O_m\in O\,\,(m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}), \bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}\in O$.

if the initial $O$ that one chose at first meets all three conditions (*legal*), then we call $X=(X, O)$ a topological space. So to answer the question on nested intervals, there have to be **infinitely many** open sets to intersect and get a single point, which doesn't satisfy (3.) condition and doesn't necessary lead to the fact that a single point is an open set. But the topology based on open intervals itself is *legal* because it doesn't contradict with all three terms.

Comment: Why you mentioned single point? I can intersect several intervals and get the smallest one, which is in $O$, but *not open* in traditional sense. If these elements are *not open* and belong to the topology so how can I define the notion of continuous mapping? At the end of the day, it relies on definition of *open* sets from calculus.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a topological space is to retain some desirable properties of metric spaces. take any topological set which is not a metric space, since the notion of distance is not defined we have to come up with ways to define continuous maps, which can only be done with open sets. So we create open sets through various techniques two of them are very obvious discrete topological space and indiscrete topological space, for further ideas study Sierpinski's space